# Is VC++ 2010 broken when using Link Time Code Generation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a base-class with some virtual functions:

```
class cs
{
   <snip>
   virtual  void    Deactivate()    =   0;
   virtual  void    Update()    =   0;
   virtual  void    Render()    =   0;
   <snip>
};
```

I then derive a class from this base class, which has it's Update() and Render functions. Which I call, thus:

```
if (s_pActiveScene)
{
   s_pActiveScene->Update();
}
```

NOTE: s_pActiveScene is a pointer to the derived class.

Everything works fine when I run the C code on iOS, Android, Mac. It also works on Windows in Debug mode (no optimisation). However the call (s_pActiveScene->Update();) crashes on the Windows Release version (only with Whole Program Optimisation = Use Link Time Code Generation).

Is it a flaw with the compiler, or something I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Getting same behavior from a new project, with minimal code as follows:

---- main.cpp

```
#include "cs.h"
#include "csMain.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Main.ActivateThisScene();
    cs::DoUpdate();
    return 0;
}
```

---- cs.h

```
#pragma once
class cs
{
public:
    void    ActivateThisScene();
    static  void    DoUpdate();
    virtual void    Update()        =   0;
protected:
    static  cs*     s_pActiveScene;
};
```

---- cs.cpp

```
#include "cs.h"
cs* cs::s_pActiveScene = 0;
void cs::ActivateThisScene()
{
    s_pActiveScene = this;
}
void cs::DoUpdate()
{
    if (s_pActiveScene)
    {
        s_pActiveScene->Update();
    }
}
```

---- csMain.h

```
#pragma once
#include "cs.h"
extern  class   csMain  Main;
class csMain : public cs  
{
public:
    void    Activate();
    void    Update();
};
```

---- csMain.cpp

```
#include "csMain.h"
class   csMain  Main;
void
csMain::Activate()
{
    ActivateThisScene();
}
void
csMain::Update()
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Your question is too vague. (Supply a minimal but complete example that demonstrates the problem for us to test.) In any case, it *could* be a bug in the compiler, but it is *far* more likely in such a putatively simple case as this that you have a latent bug somewhere, perhaps in a location unrelated to this call to `Update()`. Wayward pointers, going beyond the bounds of your allocated memory, and uninitialized variables are the most common causes of such strange symptoms -- what the standard calls "undefined behavior."

Comment: Most likely your program has undefined behavior due to mundane mistakes like uninited variable or buffer overrun, and manifests in different ways. Certainly we did see actual bugs in compilers, especially in optimizers but the chances for user bug is over 1000:1

Comment: Thank you all. <snip> is in place of unrelated code, that I omitted for the sake of brevity. I also tried checking that the pointer was equal to the instantiated object, before calling (it was), which to my mind rules out an uninitiated pointer. Also, inside the Update function itself, I tried just immediately returning; which didn't help. I'm inclined to agree though, it's such a basic a thing, the compiler should handle it without issue; struggling to understand where I could have gone wrong though. I'll try creating a new project and recreating it, with bare minimum code. Thanks.

Comment: undefined behavior need not be introduced around that point, could happen way earlier.

Comment: Okay. Just created a fresh VC++ 2010 project. Minimal code. Works in debug mode. Crashes in release mode (haven't fiddled with any project settings, just using the defaults, with Use Link Time Code Generation optimisation). So, looks like a 1 out of 1000 situation? Will try and edit to post new code...

Comment: Complete VC2010 project and source availalable here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3858786/compiler-flaw.zip --- Can anyone point out the flaw in my code? Thanks.

Comment: Is this SP1 or RTM? I know for a fact that the RTM VS2010 had an optimizer but that prevented some Qt applications from working. Installing SP1 and recompiling fixed this bug.

Comment: Yep, this is with SP1 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a problem. Either it is related to static variable initialization order or it is a code generator bug indeed.

This is the machine code

```
    Main.ActivateThisScene();

01361000  mov         eax,dword ptr [Main (1363064h)]  
01361005  mov         edx,dword ptr [eax]  ; this is supposed to be the 1st entry of VMT, but it is 0
01361007  mov         ecx,offset Main (1363064h)  
0136100C  mov         dword ptr [cs::s_pActiveScene (13633BCh)],ecx  

    cs::DoUpdate();
01361012  call        edx  ; access violation
```

Did you try to post your code to VC forum on social.msdn.microsoft.com?

Answer (score 1):

It's mixing polymorphism and statics, you can fix it like this:

```
//in csMain.cpp delete this static object
csMain  Main;

//in main.cpp create it dynamically
csMain *p = new csMain;
p->ActivateThisScene();
cs::DoUpdate();
delete p;
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. Is mixing polymorphism and statics not allowed in C++?